# Set and get tuple fail cause

Tags: apache-storm

Is it possible to communicate the cause of tuple failure from a bolt that failed it to the spout that emitted it? I want to have different logic in the spout fail method for some of the fail causes.

Answer (score 0):

Since `public void fail(Object id)` only takes the id you will probably need to manage this yourself.

Inside your bolt, persist the tuple id along with the fail cause somewhere (distributed key/value store perhaps?).

Comment: Is there a way to get a root tuple id from an arbitrary tuple in an arbitrary bolt? If I make a msgId as a custom class I could make some setters and getters, I only need to get it from a tuple somehow downstream. Strange that Storm doesn't let you access and alter the msgId object (at least some fields).

Comment: I am not familiar with distributed key/value store. Is that something like Redis?

Comment: Yep something like redis, cassandra, hbase... just need something to store the lookup of [tuple id] -> [failure cause].